# Keep running airflow trigger in foreground

Tags: airflow, bamboo

I am trying to trigger airflow from bamboo and trying to keep it running it in the foreground so bamboo can know when is the execution of trigger is complete.

Can someone suggest how can I make bamboo wait for execution of airflow trigger on remote server? 
Is it possible to capture the result if airflow dag execution was successful so bamboo can mark the build fail or success?

Comment: So i infer that problem boils down to notifying bamboo about Airflow's DAG execution completion. If you are looking for **reactive notification**, you can add a task at the end of Airflow DAG that notifies bamboo using some communications mechanism like SNS. Or else if **poll-based notification** is acceptable, then you can have bamboo looking into Airflow's meta-db for status of `DagRun`

Comment: @y2k-shubham please have a look at the EDIT in code, this solution is working for me.

Comment: Ok so you are using poll based method but instead of directly querying the meta db, you are employing Airflow CLI. I suggest you add this as an answer here

Comment: @y2k-shubham added my edit as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

After triggering airflow dag, capture the execution_date and keep checking the dag_status after every few seconds, and return if status is 'success' or 'failed'.

here is the script I wrote:

try_log.py

```
import re
import os
import sys
import time

f = open('log.txt', 'r')
outs = f.readlines()
regex = r"Created.*?@(.*?)\s(.*?)manual"
matches = re.findall(regex, str(outs), re.MULTILINE)

dag_exec_date = matches[0][1].strip()[0:-1]

status = 'running'

while status not in ['failed', 'success']:
    stream = os.popen("airflow dag_state dag_id '{}'".format(dag_exec_date))
    output = stream.read()

    lines = output.split('\n')
    status = lines[-2].strip()

    if status not in ['failed', 'success']:
        time.sleep(60)

    else:
        print (status)
        exit()
```

the following below is added in Bamboo SSH task to execute the airflow trigger and wait for status completion

```
airflow trigger_dag ${bamboo.dag_id} > /path/log.txt
outputs=$(python try_log.py)
if [ "$outputs" = "failed" ]; then
    echo "status failed. Exiting and failing build"
    exit 125
fi
```